# Run various queries based on a combo box selection

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu, vba

I have a form where a user will select a value from a dropdown. Based on this selection, I would like a series of queries to execute. For example, if a user selects 'A', then queries 1, 2 and 4 would execute. If user selects 'B', then queries 4, 2, 3 and 5 would execute in that order. The number of queries will vary and so will the order in which they are executed. 
I have a 'query subscription' table that contains all of the queries to be executed by each possible value in the dropdown and their execution order.

```
tbl_subcription:
 RowID: autonumber     
 SubscriptionID: User selected query list identifier
 QrySequence: Query execution order, unique within each SubscriptionID
 QryName: Name of query to be run
```

Sample:

```
RowID  SubscriptionID  QrySequence  QryName
 1     A               1           qry1
 2     A               2           qry2
 3     A               3           qry4
 4     B               1           qry4
 5     B               2           qry2
 6     B               3           qry3
 7     B               4           qry5
```

I want something like:

```
For each query in QryList (filtered with SubscriptionID, sorted by QrySequence)
    execute query
Next query
...Display results...
```

I'm not using dynamic queries, nor do any queries require additional parameters. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a query which retrieves the *QryName* values from rows whose *SubscriptionID* matches the dropdown selection ... a query something like this:

```sql
SELECT QryName
FROM tbl_subcription
WHERE SubscriptionID = [dropdown]
ORDER BY QrySequence;
```

Then you can open a `DAO.Recordset` based on that query, move through the recordset rows, and execute each *QryName*:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT QryName FROM tbl_subcription " & _
    "WHERE SubscriptionID = [dropdown] ORDER BY QrySequence;"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
qdf.Parameters("dropdown").Value = Me.YourDropdownName.Value
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        db.Execute !QryName, dbFailOnError
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
```

Replace *YourDropdownName* with the name of your dropdown control (combo or list box).

That code expects *YourDropdownName* is contained on the form which also contains that code.  If the code and *YourDropdownName* are not both contained in the same form, you can reference the dropdown via its parent form's name in the `Forms` collection:

```vb
Forms!YourFormName!YourDropdownName
```

Comment: Eureka! Thanks, HansUp.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you say `The number of queries will vary and so will the order in which they are executed`.  It sounds like a function accepting a ParamArray would handle what you are looking for.

Something like this:

```
Public Function RunQueries(ParamArray QueriesToRun())

    Dim i          As Long
    Dim lngUBound  As Long


    'If the ParamArray is not empty
    If UBound(QueriesToRun) >= 0 Then
        lngUBound = UBound(QueriesToRun)

        'For each value in ParamArray
        For i = 0 To lngUBound
            `Run Query: QueriesToRun(i)
        Next

    End If
End Function
```

This is untested code but I think everything is correct and should do what you are looking for. I have only ever used a `ParamArray` once though so the syntax might be slightly off.

Comment: HansUp, your example is exactly the query that I use to select all the records/queries to be executed. I save the value from the dropdown in a global variable for use by other parts of the project (its actually a string), but that is a minor detail. Now the next step is to loop through this recordset, executing the unknown number of queries one by one.

Comment: Newd, whereas your solution will work, I will have hundreds of different cases, with anywhere from 1 to 20 queries each, requiring someone with coding skills to add/modify this list. I'm looking for a solution that only requires some basic record adjustments in the tbl_subscription to add, delete or modify the sequences to be executed.

Comment: Makes sense, I have updated my answer, it would handle your looping issue if you are able to send it an array of SQL queries to be run.   Also your HansUp comment is on the wrong answer :-).  And I should also say that his actually does handle the looping as well.  Where he says: `Do While Not .EOF
        db.Execute !QryName, dbFailOnError
        .MoveNext
    Loop`

Comment: Thanks, Newd.  Sorry about the comment to the wrong answer. This is my first post- I'm still figuring out how this works. :)